Nonpositively/nonnegatively curved metric spaces: trying to match the definition and the intuition
I am reading "A course in metric geometry" by Burago & Ivanov. I just learned the definition of a nonpositively/nonnegatively curved metric space, and I want to gain intuition so that the curvatures of the common examples are obvious to me.
The definition given in the book is more or less the following. $(X,d)$ is the geodesic metric space we want to measure the curvature.
Definition. For fixed $p\in X$ and a shortest path $\gamma:[0,T]\to X$ parametrized by arc length, the function $g:[0,T]\to [0,\infty), \gamma(t)=d_p\circ \gamma(t)$ is called a $1$-dimensional distance function.
Definition. For a pair $(p,\gamma(t))$ or a point $p\in X$ and a shortest path $\gamma:[0,T]\to X$ parametrized by arc length, a Euclidean comparison segment $\gamma_0:[0,T]\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is any segment that has the same length as $\gamma$.
Definition. For a pair $(p,\gamma(t))$ or a point $p\in X$ and a shortest path $\gamma:[0,T]\to X$ parametrized by arc length, a Euclidean comparison point is a point $\bar{p}\in \mathbb{R}^2$ so that $d(\gamma(0),p)=d_{E}(\gamma_0(0),\bar{p}),d(\gamma(1),p)=d_{E}(\gamma_0(1),\bar{p}) $ where $d_E$ is the Euclidean distance on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\gamma_0$ is a Euclidean comparison segment.
Definition. Given a 1-dimensional distance function $g$, the comparison function for $g$ is $g_0(t)=d_E(\bar{p},\gamma_0(t))$ where $\bar{p},\gamma_0$ are Euclidean comparison point/segment.
Definition. We say that $(X,d)$ is nonpositively (resp. nonnegatively) curved if every point in $X$ has a neighborhood such that, whenever a point $p$ and a segment $\gamma$ lie within this neighborhood, the comparison function $g_0$ for the 1-dimensional distance function $g(t)=d(p,\gamma(t))$ satisfies $g_0(t)\leq g(t)$ (resp. $g_0(t) \geq g(t)$) for all $t\in [0,T]$.
Now, it is commonly said that the sphere has a nonnegative curvature and a saddle-like surface has a nonpositive curvature (see the following image):

However, I am unable to see why immediately from the definition. The question is as follows: Is there a quick way to check why the surfaces above have a given curvature using the definitions above? In particular, is there an easy way to find a comparison point/segment for a given curve and a point on the surface?
Edit: As discussed in the comment, the following is my attempt to prove that $g_0=g$ when the metric space $(X,d)$ is a plane in $\mathbb{R}^n$. That is, $X= \{su+tv|s,t\in \mathbb{R}\}$ where $u,v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ are orthonormal vectors (we can take $u,v$ to be orthonormal by Gram-Schmidt). Since the geodesics are straight lines, the distance $d$ on $X$ is just the Euclidean distance.
First, we prove that the mapping $\phi:X\to \mathbb{R}^2, su+tv\mapsto (s,t)$ is an isometry. First, it is bijective since $u,v$ are linearly independent, implying the uniqueness of the coefficients of $s,t$.
Now, we prove that $p$ preserves the distance, for any $s_0u+t_0v, s_1u+t_1v\in X$, we have
$d(s_0u+t_0v, s_1u+t_1v) = \|s_0u+t_0v - s_1u-t_1v\| = \|(s_0-s_1)u+(t_0-t_1)v\|$
where $\|\cdot \|$ is the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
By definition of the Euclidean distance, we have
$\|(s_0-s_1)u+(t_0-t_1)v\|^2= (s_0-s_1)^2\|u\|^2 +2(s_0-s_1)(t_0-t_1)(u,v)+(t_0-t_1)^2 $
where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the Euclidean inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $u,v$ are assumed to be orthonormal, we have $\|u\|^2=1 \|v\|^2=1, (u,v)=0$, so
$\|(s_0-s_1)u+(t_0-t_1)v\|^2= (s_0-s_1)^2 +(t_0-t_1)^2 $
Therefore $d(s_0u+t_0v,s_1u+t_1v)= \sqrt{(s_0-s_1)^2+(t_0-t_1)^2}$, and since the RHS is the Euclidean distance on $\mathbb{R}^2$, the mapping $\phi$ preserves the distance. This concludes the proof that $\phi$ is an isometry.
Now, we consider a 1-dimensional distance function and its comparison function. Take any $p\in X$ and a segment $\gamma:[0,T]\to X, \gamma(t)=a+\frac{t}{T}(b-a)$ where $a,b\in X$ and $T=d(a,b)$. Define the 1-dimensional distance function $g(t) = d(p,\gamma(t))$ for $(p,\gamma)$. Now, the comparison points/segment can be obtained by $\bar{p}=\phi(p), \gamma_0(t)=\phi(\gamma(t))$.
$\bar{p}$ and $\gamma_0(t)$ satisfies the definition of comparison point/segment since $\phi$ is an isometry. Now, the comparison function of $g$ is $g_0(t)=\|\gamma_0(t)-\bar{p}\|$, which is equal to $g$ by isometry, so $X$ is both nonpositive and nonnegative curved.

Can you do this for the Euclidean plane?  For sphere and hyperbolic plane you need to know some hyperbolic/spherical trigonometry (or Riemannian geometry). In general, comparison points are easy to find, what is difficult is to find comparison distances.

@MoisheKohan I think, given a plane in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I can use the parametrization of the plane to identify the plane as $\mathbb{R}^2$, and finding comparison point/segment should be trivial. So, to me, it is intuitively clear why $g_0$ would be equal to $g$ in this case. I would like to gain intuition on why (say) sphere should satisfy $g_0\geq g$.

Try to get from "intuitive" to rigorous at least in the Euclidean plane. And write a proof in the body of your post, not in a comment.

@MoisheKohan I have added the attempt in the question. Please let me know if you have any comments.
